# recording delay

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording

I'm writing an app in Android Studio where I need to synchronously start recording audio on 2 different devices. My program will have to detect the delay between the 2 devices, based on the distance of the sound source.

Unfortunately, even though my program has a very precise timer and sends recorder.start() at given time, there is a delay (less than 0,5 second) before the time and the actual beginning of the audio recording.

Is there any way to measure the delay, to start the recording a bit earlier?
If not, is there any way to eliminate the delay?

I've seen a question about the delay, but the solution was to simply make sure the recording has started, then start making sounds, but it doesn't help me, since I have to start recording at the **exact** same time on two android devices. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    int i = 0;
    while((wavFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/JavaApps/"+"output" + i + ".mp4")).isFile())
        i++;
    finalName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/JavaApps/"+"output" + i + ".mp4";
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFile(wavFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        recorder.prepare();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

^ all this happens as a preparation, before the recording has to start

```
    recorder.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(duration*1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    recorder.stop();

    recorder.release();
    recorder = null;
```

^ this part happens when the time reaches the set value.

Comment: I don't know enough about Android audio APIs to get into the specifics, but you'll probably have to drop to a lower-level API to get that kind of timing precision.

Comment: I'm quite new to Java and Android, so - without a proper guide there is no way I could figure it out all by myself :/

Comment: Hopefully someone else here who has experience with Android audio APIs can weigh in and give some information